# Xcode organizer copy failed

Tags: xcode, archive, xcode-organizer

[image]

Anybody faced this issue while exporting iOS app to tester team?

Answer (score 40):

In my case it was the disk space. I had to free up some space before running it again.

Comment: When we got out of disk space, a lot strange things happen...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Meet Dave answer, I'd like to give little more details:

when that error showed up, among distribution log files we could see in `IDEDistributionPipeline.log` a number of `ditto:` commands that ended up with a message `No space left on device`:

```
2021-03-25 19:05:28 +0000  copying file <<some project file>> ... 
2021-03-25 19:05:29 +0000  ditto: 
2021-03-25 19:05:29 +0000  /private/var/folders/kf/<<removed for simplicity>>/<<some project file>>: No space left on device
```